# Fill data down based on prior Row information similar to Excel auto-fill

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access Database table with 3 fields.  I need to populate a 4th field with the results from the 3rd field of a prior Row/record.  However I need it to keep populating that same result down until certain criteria in field 1 is met, then it should change what is being filled down and start populating the new results down.

Example of existing data

```
    ID--Field1--Field2
    01-----A-----ACH
    02-----H-----7
    03-----D-----Sun
    04-----A-----DTD
    05-----H-----123456
    06-----T-----9
    07-----B-----Moon
    08-----P-----1
    09-----A-----EBX
    10-----H-----Stars
    11-----T-----25
    12-----B-----97Street
```

I want the data to populate Field 3 with the same results in each row until the criteria in Field 1 = "A" and then change to what Field 2 is for the next group.  (having a hard time explaining sorry)

Example of what I want:

```
    ID--Field1--Field2---Field 3
    01-----A-----ACH-----ACH
    02-----H-----7-------ACH
    03-----D-----Sun-----ACH
    04-----A-----DTD-----DTD
    05-----H-----123456--DTD
    06-----T-----9-------DTD
    07-----B-----Moon----DTD
    08-----P-----1-------DTD
    09-----A-----EBX-----EBX
    10-----H-----Stars---EBX
    11-----T-----25------EBX
    12-----B-----97St----EBX
```

I built a query that does this but locks up the system because it is too cumbersome.

Field3: IIf([field1]="A",[field2],(DLookUp("[Field3]","Query1","[ID]=" & [ID]-1)))

Basically I use the If statement to get when the Change should happen and the Dlookup to pull whatever was in the prior line of Field 3.  You can see why it might be cumbersome when processing hundreds of records.

I searched through many resources and found similar problems with solutions and sql code to pull the prior information but can't seem to find a solution to populate down until the next "A" is found in Field 1.

Please help!!!  Thanks